# Java regular expression to match everything between same specific character sequences

Tags: java, regex

Let's take string `"Something foo part1 foo part2 foo part3"` as an example.

I want to find all parts starting with "foo" continuing till another "foo" or end of string and replace (wrap inner part into HTML markup) afterwards. So the result should be `"Something <bar> part1 </bar><bar> part2 </bar><bar> part3</bar>"`

I've started with: `"foo(.*?)(foo|$)"` and replacing it with `"<bar>$1</bar>"`. Replacing seems to be all right but I need help with regex itself.

I have tried many variations with negative lookbehind and others so far without success. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your second group into a lookahead

```
foo(.*?)(?=foo|$)
```

[See it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?359qp)

The problem is you are matching the "foo" that you want to use as next start point. You can avoid this by using the [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This way the following "foo" is not matched and therefor used as start of the next match.